# How can i convert uv coordinates to world space?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, cg, shaderlab

I am trying to implement a shader. It will use with Unity LineRenderer. Shader will have noise that scrolling overtime raltive to texture coordinates. For example in parallel to x axis of uv space of texture. I have an implementation, but i dont'know how to get direction relative to texture uv (consider the texture rotation) in a vert function. I am only have a world space-relativew scrolling.

Main problem - how to convert uv coordinates (for example (0, 0) or (1, 0)) to world space?

Here is a my shader:

```
Shader "LineRendering/Test"
{
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}

        _Freq("Frequency", Float) = 1
        _Speed("Speed", Float) = 1
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            "Queue" = "Transparent"
            "IgnoreProjector" = "True"
            "RenderType" = "Transparent"
            "PreviewType" = "Plane"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas" = "True"
        }

        LOD 200

        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        Fog { Mode Off }
        Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma target 3.0          
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma enable_d3d11_debug_symbols

            #include "noiseSimplex.cginc"

            struct appdata_t
            {
                fixed4 vertex : POSITION;
                fixed2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                fixed4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                fixed2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
                fixed2 srcPos : TEXCOORD1;

            };

            uniform fixed _Freq;
            uniform fixed _Speed;


            v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
            {
                v2f OUT;

                OUT.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN.vertex);

                OUT.texcoord = IN.uv;
                OUT.srcPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, IN.vertex).xy;
                OUT.srcPos *= _Freq;

                //This is my trying to convert uv coordinates to world coodinates, but it is still unsuccessfully.

                //fixed2 v0Pos = mul(unity_WorldToObject, fixed3(0, 0, 0)).xy;
                //fixed2 v1Pos = mul(unity_WorldToObject, fixed3(1, 0, 0)).xy;
                //fixed2 scrollOffset = v1Pos - v0Pos;

                fixed2 scrollOffset = fixed2(1, 0);
                OUT.srcPos.xy -= fixed2(scrollOffset.x, scrollOffset.y) * _Time.y * _Speed;

                return OUT;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : COLOR
            {
                fixed4 output;
                float ns = snoise(IN.srcPos) / 2 + 0.5f;

                output.rgb = fixed3(ns, ns, ns);
                output.a = ns;

                output.rgb *= output.a;
                return output;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Noise library getted form here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/2d-3d-4d-optimised-perlin-noise-cg-hlsl-library-cginc.218372/#post-2445598. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texture coordinates are already in texture space.  If I understand correctly, you should be able to just do this:

```
    v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
    {
        v2f OUT;

        OUT.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN.vertex);

        OUT.texcoord = IN.uv;
        OUT.srcPos = IN.uv;
        OUT.srcPos *= _Freq;

        fixed2 scrollOffset = fixed2(1, 0);
        OUT.srcPos.xy -= fixed2(scrollOffset.x, scrollOffset.y) * _Time.y * _Speed;

        return OUT;
    }
```

Comment: I am already try to use OUT.srcPos = IN.uv instead OUT.srcPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, IN.vertex).xy. Scrolling work right, but i have another problem.


If i use vertex as scrpos output looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/tHYit1H.png


But if i use uv it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/TNesNad.png


And i don't have some informatoion about aspect ration of texture in the shader. So this way is wrong, as i think. If you have an idea how i can discover aspect ration in vertex shader, it wiil be way to solve this issue.

Comment: Your uv coordinates are stretched!  To get texture coordinates with uniform texel density, you can call Unwrapping.GeneratePerTriangleUV on your mesh in one of your monobehavior start() methods.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unwrapping.GeneratePerTriangleUV.html

You might need to specify UnwrapParam to get the result you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, but I have not any mesh for use as function parameter. I use this shader with LineRenderer so mesh is inaccessible and can be changed at runtime throw LineRenderer.Position property.

Comment: Oh, just set LineRenderer.textureMode to tile.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

Each of your UVs is associated with a specific vertex. Once you can establish which UV is assigned to which vertex, then look up the world position of the vertex.

## Option 2

Another way to do this though may be with a texture that is a pre-baked image of the local space coordinates of the object. In the texture, the XYZ coords would map to RGB. Then you'll do a texture lookup and get to local object coordinates. You'll then have to multiply that vector by the world projection matrix in order to get the actual world space value.

When you create the texture, you'll have to account for the inability to store negative values. So first you'll have to set up the object so that it fits entirely inside the world coordinates of [-1, 1], in all three axes. Then, as part of the baking procedure, you'll have to divide all values by two, and then add .5. This will ensure that all your negative coordinate space values are stored from [0,.5) and all positive values are stored from [.5,1].

---

### Note

I had a hard time understanding your exact request. I hope my options help with your program

Comment: 1. Yes, I know about uv coordinates of each vertex. But in vertex shader it is possible only for one vertex at a time. But for calculating direction vector I need two vertices. So it will not work.

Comment: 2. Pre-baking of texture are not the solution, cause I do not use any texture, and local coordinates will change at runtime (LineRenderer will change it's scale).


Whatever, thank for advises.

Comment: Do you have an example, of what this will look like? Can you do a quick comp in Photoshop to illustrate the effect you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Local coordinates of your object will change at run time, do you mean you have a deformable mesh?

Comment: Yes, mesh is deformable and I have no access to the mesh, cause this is LineRenderer component. 

I already find solution in comments to above answer, but thank you for you answers!