# How to convert world position to UV - space?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, transformation

I have a gameObject1 which transmit it's position into shader of some screenGameObject. ScreenGameObject has position(0,0,0), rotation(0,0,0), scale(1,1,1).

In the shader I need to make a texture follow this gameObject1.

In general, I think, need to convert world position of gameObject1 to uv - space of ScreenGameObject.

Here I have found some task, which is v close to my: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852185/how-can-i-convert-uv-coordinates-to-world-space)

In the vertex shader I wrote :

```
o.uvOffset = mul(unity_WorldToObject, _FrameTexPos).xy;
```

In frag function I have:

```
return tex2D(_AimTex, i.uvOffset).rrrr;
```

As result: the _AimTex texture moves wrongly at all:
_FrameTexPos.x makes texture move along OY, _FrameTexPos.y makes it move along local OX

I guess this:

```
mul(unity_WorldToObject, _FrameTexPos).xy;
```

Do not convert _FrameTexPos rightly (from world space, to object's uv space).

Comment: Have you looked at [Camera.WorldToScreenPoint()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html)?

Comment: Yes, I know this function. But I'm need move texture in shader.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't understand the problem you have.

Comment: I have a game object and it should have a shade on the plane. This shade is a texture which fllow to this game object. I think I have solved this problem, but not finished it yet.

Comment: If you consider the case of your aim object hitting the corner of a cube, you will realize that your problem doesn't have enough information to be solveable in a way that looks good.  This also goes for any texture unwrap that is not continuous.  Are you sure the Unity3d Projector behavior doesn't do what you are looking for?  If you really need to transform world space into texture space, you can use barycentric coordinates to do it.